# Calculating multivariate relative importance in R

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis

I'm in the process of evaluating some behavioral data I've collected and cannot find a package to obtain relative factor importance for the following linear model:

`cbind(accuracy, rt) ~ A + B + C + D`

In an earlier, parallel – but univariate – experiment I was able to use the `relaimpo` R package, which worked fine. But it is unable, I believe, to support multivariate analysis. I'm aware of Tonidandel & LeBreton's [online tool/downloadable R code](http://relativeimportance.davidson.edu/multivariateregression.html), but was hoping their might be an alternative package-based solution. Am I in luck, or is their code the best bet out there right now?